# Is it valid to invert my classifier's output in order to improve forecasting results?

Tags: classification, forecasting, accuracy

I have research about forecasting, and the output of my forecasting is either "low" or "high."  Based on my classifier's output, the forecast accuracy is low. Is it valid to invert the predicted forecast to improve my accuracy?

For example, I have 10 instances who predicted and actual outputs are:

> **# / Predicted / Actual**
>   1 / Low / High
>   2 / Low / High
>   3 / Low / High
>   4 / Low / High
>   5 / Low / High
>   6 / Low / High
>   7 / Low / High
>   8 / High / Low
>   9 / High / Low
>   10 / High / Low

Is it valid to invert my forecast output? Is there a theoretical basis for the answer either way?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, it's your forecast. However, it wouldn't make a sense.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are generating your forecasts, but assuming that you are using some sort of classifier to come up with a decision boundary then the answer is "YES." This is for two reasons:

1. Your decision boundary is very capable of separating **low** and **high** forecasts. In the example data you give it is actually perfect: all of the **low** forecasts are on one side of the boundary and all of the **high** forecasts are on the other;
2. The problem then is how the decision boundary is being interpreted and how **low**/**high** labels are being assigned to the forecasts. Since your forecasts are well separated but improperly labelled, it makes sense to adjust your mechanism for labelling data by inverting it.

Comment: any journal or research that do the same thing? link? :)

Comment: @MasBiru It's hard to be specific given the lack of detail in your question, but I outlined a possible approach in my answer: "The problem then is how the decision boundary is being interpreted and how low/high labels are being assigned to the forecasts. Since your forecasts are well separated but improperly labelled, it makes sense to adjust your mechanism for labelling data by inverting it."

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "Yes, you can".
But you better investigate why your current predictor have so low quality.

Comment: Any reason? do you ever read research like that? :) which is reverse the output?